# Handle multiple Angular observables

Tags: angular, typescript, http, observable

I am a beginner with Angular and TypeScript, so I am creating my own application using the public Pokemon API for practice. However, I want some feedback on the task to use http to get information on the pokemons with ids between [1, 50]. To get the Pokemon for each id, I need a separate http GET request. As a result, I have 50 Observable objects that I need to subscribe to and then generate an array out of the results from all 50 Observables. However, I want some advice on if there exists a better way to achieve what I am hoping to.

**poke-dashboard.component.ts (Code to subscribe to 50 Observables)**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PokemonService } from '../services/pokemon.service';
import { Pokemon } from '../shared/pokemon';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-poke-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './poke-dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./poke-dashboard.component.scss'],
})
export class PokeDashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  pokemons: Pokemon[];

  constructor(private pokemonservice: PokemonService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let pokemonsList: Pokemon[] = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
      this.pokemonservice.getPokemonForId(i).subscribe((data: any) => {
        pokemonsList.push(this.pokemonservice.generatePokemon(data));
      });
    }
    this.pokemons = pokemonsList;
  }
}
```

**pokemon.service.ts (Code to handle http calls)**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Pokemon } from '../shared/pokemon';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PokemonService {
  baseUrl: string;
  private pokemons: Pokemon[] = [
    new Pokemon(
      'pikachu',
      'pikachu',
      90,
      50,
      50,
      40,
      55,
      35,
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/25.png'
    ),
  ];
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.baseUrl = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/';
  }

  public getPokemonForId(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.baseUrl + `pokemon/${id}`);
  }

  public generatePokemon(pokeinfo: any): Pokemon {
    return new Pokemon(
      pokeinfo['name'],
      pokeinfo['species']['name'],
      pokeinfo['stats'][0]['base_stat'],
      pokeinfo['stats'][1]['base_stat'],
      pokeinfo['stats'][2]['base_stat'],
      pokeinfo['stats'][3]['base_stat'],
      pokeinfo['stats'][4]['base_stat'],
      pokeinfo['stats'][5]['base_stat'],
      pokeinfo['sprites']['front_default']
    );
  }

  public getPokemons() {
    return this.pokemons;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about what "a better way" means? Just cleaner code, or do you want to send several requests at a time, or limit the number of requests that you want to send before having a response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you starting with Angular and RxJS, I wouldn't recommend PokeAPI to learn it with. It is a little complicated to obtain information from.

Neverthless, it contains hypertext media in the result. Instead of using a `for` loop, you could obtain URLs for each ID using this hypertext media. A GET request to the URL `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=3&offset=0` fetches the following result.

```
{
  "count": 964,
  "next": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?offset=3&limit=3",
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "name": "bulbasaur",
      "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/"
    },
    {
      "name": "ivysaur",
      "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/"
    },
    {
      "name": "venusaur",
      "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/"
    }
  ]
}
```

You could make a request with parameter `limit=50` if you need the first 50 entries. Now we could obtain all the URLs and make the HTTP requests. Instead of subscribing to it individually, we could use RxJS [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) which allows us to subscribe to multiple observables.

If you are starting with Angular, it might a little too much. I'd say to go at it one thing at a time. I'd recommend you to start with the [Angular Tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial). It introduces the basics.

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular9-http-client-pokeapi-tkjxpk)

pokemon-api.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

import { of, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

export const BASE_URL = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2';

@Injectable()
export class PokemonApiService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public getListOfPokemon(limit: string, offset ?: string) {
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('offset', offset ? offset : '0')
      .set('limit', limit);
    return this.httpClient
      .get<any>(`${BASE_URL}/pokemon`, { observe: 'response', params: params })
      .pipe(
        map(res => res.body.results),
        catchError(error => of(error.url))
      );
  }

  public getPokemonDetails(urlList: Array<any>) {
    urlList = urlList.map(url => this.httpClient.get<any>(url));
    return forkJoin(urlList);
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { PokemonApiService } from './pokemon-api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  pokemons = [];
  limit = '50';

  constructor(private _pokemonApiService: PokemonApiService) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getPokemonList();
  }

  private getPokemonList() {
    this._pokemonApiService.getListOfPokemon(this.limit).subscribe(
      response => { this.getPokemonDetails(response.map(response => response.url)); },
      error => { console.error(error); }
    );
  }

  private getPokemonDetails(urlList: Array<string>) {
    this._pokemonApiService.getPokemonDetails(urlList).subscribe(
      response => { this.pokemons = response; },
      error => { console.error(error); }
    );
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Sprite</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let pokemon of pokemons">
    <td>{{ pokemon.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ pokemon.name | titlecase }}</td>
    <td><img [src]="pokemon.sprites.front_default"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```